# Converting date to UTC timestamp

Tags: node.js, date, date-fns

I have the following date 2022-02-24T17:30:00.0000000 in UTC. I'm not sure what format it is in, but I need to convert it into a utc timestamp. How can I do that? I tried using

```
var parseISO = require('date-fns/parseISO');

parseISO("2022-02-24T17:30:00.0000000").getTime()
```

but that's not giving me the right timestamp.

Can someone please help?

Comment: There's no such thing as a UTC timestamp. Timestamps are a count of seconds or milliseconds since 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z

Comment: If your string is missing any timezone info and it's actually UTC, try suffixing it with `Z`... `parseISO("2022-02-24T17:30:00.0000000Z")`